# Product Page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, products, 404-page, 404

How to create product page in Magento 2 like here.

[image]

When I click on product it goes to `404 error`.

Comment: can you explain more here. what is the theme you are using

Comment: I use default magento blank theme

Comment: I just want to make product page like on this picture

Comment: run 

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex  and clear cache and try

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what you tell me to do. I use only magento 2 admin site to make configurations on my website. I don't know how to use backend files. I only transfer some data through Filezilla on sever. Could you explain me?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps,

- Try re-indexing using the Magento 2 CLI

Login to your server via SSH and go to Magento root directory and run the below command

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

- Remove the cache from the server

rm –rf var/cache var/generation var/pagecache var/di

- Re-compile the magento

php bin/magento setup:di:compile